# Как изменить отступ уже написанному коду?

Tags: python, pycharm, перемещение

Столкнулся с проблемой перемещения кода. К примеру, я написал какой-то код и потом решил его добавить в цикл или в оператор и тд. Как мне весь имеющийся код переместить во внутрь того что я хочу. В ручную работать с BackSpace и Enter неудобно.

Напрмер этот:

```
while pop < 5:
for i in range(1):
sys = random.randint(1, 10)
en = int(input("Угадай: "))
  if en == sys:
     pop = 0
     print("Угадал")
```

Как все это за раз переместить в While?

Comment: Vim: `/for<Enter>` - переносим курсор на `for`. `>}` - смещаем блок под `while`. `j>}` - выравниваем блок под `for`. `/if<Enter>` - переносим курсор на `if`. `==` - выравниваем строку с `if`. `j2==2>>` - выравниваем две строки под `if`. Следующий раз пишите какой вам нужен редактор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выделите весь код, который хотите подвинуть вправо и нажмите клавишу Tab. Если захотите подвинуть на табуляцию влево - Shift + Tab

```
while pop < 5:
    for i in range(1):
    sys = random.randint(1, 10)
    en = int(input("Угадай: "))
    if en == sys:
        pop = 0
        print("Угадал")
```